# Keep generating ID until it doesn't exist in database

Tags: typescript

Because i am to keep the id's in 4 digits. The chance of collision is high. So i would like to check if the id exist in my database before proceeding.

I'm generating the id in the client side. The "check if the id exist" is a promise function.

I would like to achieve something like this.

```
var databaseIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

async function generateId(): Promise<number> {
    let myId: number;

    await do {
        myId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    }
    while (await checkIfIdExist(myId));

    return myId
}

async function checkIfIdExist(id: number): Promise<boolean> {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    return databaseIds.includes(id)
}
```

Comment: You absolutely should not be generating ids for your database infrastructure in client side code.  Your server should be handling all of this in the background, away from exposure to the client. You're asking for trouble with this kind of setup.

Comment: If you are forced to check with the server if an id is available or not, couldn't you just ask the server for a list of available ids directly? As the server already know if $randomNumber is available or not, it can just tell you, and maybe even reserve it. Nothing wrong generating ids from the frontend, but your use case negate most of the reasons why you would do it there